# Ultrawide resolution does not works with nvidia driver (but works with nouveau) - 12.04

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, xrandr, display-resolution

I'm trying to get working my new UltraWide monitor (2560x1080px) via HDMI (nVidia 9500GT). By default, there is no option to select this resolution in screen settings panel, only 1920x1080p is available.

I've found a way to get working, but it's works only with the nouveau driver:

```
cvt 2560 1080 60
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode  HDMI-1 "2560x1080_60.00"
```

This is working, but after installing nVidia drivers, i've got error messages. The first interest thing is, HDMI-1 does not exists with that driver, but there is a HDMI-0 device.

I've tried to

```
xrandr --addmode  HDMI-0 "2560x1080_60.00"
```

but i've got that errors:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

What's the problem?